# ORA-01446 occurs if I try to select random rows using SAMPLE clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Since the number of rows in the table is too large I switched from "ORDER BY dbms_random.value" construction for getting 1000 random rows to SAMPLE clause. It takes less than a second instead of 3 minutes to complete. But on some tables I get this error

> ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT t1.columnA FROM 
(SELECT columnA FROM table1 sample(1) where rownum <= 1000)  t1 
JOIN table2 t2 
ON (t1.columnA = t2.columnA) 
WHERE t2.columnB IS NOT NULL
```

and it works fine on some tables, but fails on others. I gave up googling, could you please advise any workaround in my situation.

Comment: maybe some 'tables' are in fact complex views.

Comment: Oh my! Yes, you are right. What would suggest then? Create more complex query using JOIN but working with tables only?

Comment: @Alex with a view, as you can't use ROWID sampling you'd either have order by (which you said was too slow) or a somewhat random trick like `where trunc(dbms_random.value(mod(rownum, 1), 10)) = 1) and rownum <= 1000`. This would favour rows near the beginning of the result set (to get more spread randomness ,increase the "10"..at the cost of runtime)

Comment: Use Row_Number() in place of rownum.

Comment: @DazzaL your solution is faster than ORDER BY dbms_random.value but unfortunately it still takes 44 seconds when I need maximum 1 second

Comment: Would the `ORA_HASH` solution shown [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/datamining/entry/to_sample_or_not_to_sample_part_2) work for you? Not sure that's likely to meet your speed requirements either but might be worth testing to check.

Comment: @AlexPoole Tried that already. Still slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I expected SAMPLE clause works faster than all other solutions ([Here you can see some of them](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_FAQ#Can_one_select_a_random_collection_of_rows_from_a_table.3F))

Because I'm new to Oracle DBs generally and Oracle SQL Developer in particaular I mistakenly called view a "table". After I found that out the solution was clear.

SOLUTION: I had to look at the SQL query that forms a view and replace view name with that query.
For example my table1 was actually a view whose name I replaced with SELECT query that forms that view:

```
SELECT t1.columnA FROM 
(SELECT columnA FROM (select distinct tt1.columnA,  tt2.columnC
  from table22 tt2, table11 tt1
 where tt2.columnC = tt1.columnA) sample(1) where rownum <= 1000)  t1 
JOIN table2 t2 
ON (t1.columnA = t2.columnA) 
WHERE t2.columnB IS NOT NULL
```

After that I could work with tables and apply SAMPLE to them! Thank you everybody, great website! =)
PS: sorry for my English and ugly code *facepalm.jpg*